# Error during installation of android studio

Tags: android-studio

[image]

Whenever I start insatallation even thought I start as(run as administrator), it gives me the same error. Kindly help me fast.

```
Android SDK was installed to C:\Users\Muahmmad\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1
Ignoring unknown package filter 'sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-24'Ignoring unknown package filter 'addon-google_apis-google-24'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.
The following SDK components were not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-24 and addon-google_apis-google-24
```

Comment: Please try to give as much detail as possible. Could you be more specific about the error you are getting?

Comment: Android SDK was installed to C:\Users\Muahmmad\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1
Ignoring unknown package filter 'sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-24'Ignoring unknown package filter 'addon-google_apis-google-24'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.
The following SDK components were not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-24 and addon-google_apis-google-24

Comment: And then when I press Finish and click on start a new Android studio project it says "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date, or is missing templates. You can configure your SDK via Configure | Project Defaults | Project Structure | SDKs"